# Empty result in Mysql

Tags: mysql

trying to run a query in MYSQL but the result is empty:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name from users WHERE csopnev="Testvériség SE" NOT IN
(SELECT nev FROM jelentkezok where versenyId = "8" AND klubnev ="Testvériség SE");
```

or

```
SELECT a.name FROM users a, jelentkezok b WHERE a.name = b.nev AND csopnev ="Testvériség SE" 
  AND a.name NOT IN (
    SELECT nev FROM jelentkezok m WHERE versenyId = "8" AND klubnev ="Testvériség SE")
```

If I am running just the first part or second part then the expected result is there. Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name 
from users 
left join jelentkezok on users.csopnev = jelentkezok.klubnev
                     and jelentkezok.versenyId = "8" 
                     AND jelentkezok.klubnev ="Testvériség SE"
WHERE csopnev="Testvériség SE" 
and jelentkezok.klubnev is null
```